# Is it possible for a restful webservice to have a parameter in the url?

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I was instructed to create webservices ( with Spring-Boot ). My colleague gave me the url of the webservice and it looks like this : `http://172.20.40.4:8080/Oxalys_WS/stock/ITM=1559`

In general we create a `RestController` with the url :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("stock")
public class StockController {

    @Autowired
    private StockService stockService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{code}", produces = "application/json")
    public JsonModel getByCode(@PathVariable String code) {
        JsonModel jsonModel = new JsonModel();
        final Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        List<Stock> stock = stockService.getByCode(code);
        data.put("stock", stock);
        data.put("stockTotal", stockService.getTotal(code));
        jsonModel.setDatas(data);

        return jsonModel;
    }
}
```

So is it normal to create a `Restful` Spring-Boot `webservice` with a parameter in the url ?

Comment: are you specifically looking for query string parameters? If you are using HTTP GET you might need to have some query parameters with the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provides parameter in two standard way.

> 1. Query Param : http://172.20.40.4:8080/Oxalys_WS/stock?ITM=1559
> 2. Path Variable : http://172.20.40.4:8080/Oxalys_WS/stock/1559

**Query Param** :- It is a typical old way to pass some value as QueryParam with using of some variable starts with `?`(Question Mark) and value is assigned using `=`(equals).

**PathVariable** :- this is a newer pattern introduce for REST-api Services. URL must be structured such in a way that this should not look too messy if multiple parameters need to pass within a URL.

For more info [Navigate this link](https://apiguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_and_publish/use_RESTful_urls.html)

Comment: so if I want to use a Restful controller then the url should not contain any query parameters ?

Comment: REST-api url suggests not to pass .. but spring is still gives u a option to pass a query param too..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have the one in your URL
When you are required to have the path variable, you can give in the Request URL

Comment: Query Param : http://172.20.40.4:8080/Oxalys_WS/stock?ITM=1559
        Path Variable : http://172.20.40.4:8080/Oxalys_WS/stock/1559